# Can some one tell me how i can mask only front part of a car image in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a car racing  game, i want to mask front part of the car image (not the whole car image) for collision detection.
code

```
front = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.car.car_image)
offset = (int(self.car.x-x), int(self.car.y-y))
p = track.overlap(front, offset)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) of the image and then a mask from the subsurface:

```py
front_surf = self.car.car_image.subsurface((0, 0, width, front_height))
front = pygame.mask.from_surface(front_surf)
```